# Does using a blink shirt to teleport provoke attacks of opportunity?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, meldshaping

The soulmeld *blink shirt* says that the meldshaper gains

> the ability to teleport (as *dimension door*) up to 10 feet at will. Using this ability is a standard action. After using this ability, you can’t take any other actions until your
>   next turn. You cannot bring along other creatures; you affect only yourself. (*Magic of Incarnum* 61)

When a meldshaper uses the ability to teleport gained from the *blink shirt*, does the meldshaper provoke attacks of opportunity, as if casting a spell or using a spell-like ability; or does the meldshaper *not* provoke attacks of opportunity, as if using an extraordinary, natural, or supernatural ability?

Because the text doesn't categorize this ability as extraordinary, spell-like, or supernatural, by default the special ability is [natural](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm), but it just feels *wrong* to categorize as *natural* a special ability gained from a shirt woven of preincarnate souls.

Comment: I guess maybe preincarnate souls are no more supernatural than incarnate or post-incarnate ones? I mean, living people don't provoke attacks of opportunity when animating their bodies, and petitioners and incorporeal undead aren't picked up by Detect Magic...

Comment: @GMJoe Would that an explanation were that simple! Soulmeld–Magic Transparency says, "Soulmelds interact with spells and spells interact with soulmelds in the same way that a spell or a normal spell-like ability interacts with another spell or spell-like ability (with a limited number of exceptions...)" (*MoI* 52). So, yeah, I dunno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Soulmelds are their own, unique form of magic, not following the rules for supernatural abilities, spell-like abilities, or spells. The rules for them never say that they provoke attacks of opportunity when used, thus they do not; provoking is a special facet of some actions, never a default.

The fact that the *blink shirt* mimics a spell (*dimension door*) is irrelevant here: it’s not being used as a spell, it just has the effect of the spell. The *blink shirt*’s *dimension door* no more provokes attacks of opportunity than does the supernatural *dimension door* of the blink dog it came from.

Answer (score 0):

Magic of Incarnum doesn't specify what type of ability souldmelds or their powers fall under but if you have to classify it into a specific category it would most closely resemble a spell-like ability. So yes, using it would provoke an attack of opportunity.

> Magic Of Incarnum Page 52 "Incarnum and Spells"
>
> Spell resistance is effective against any soulmeld used to affect a
>   creature other than the meldshaper. A meldshaper’s spell resistance
>   (if any) is automatically overcome by his own soulmelds. Dispel magic
>   and spells of that nature interact with a soul- meld as if the
>   soulmeld were a magic item.

Supernatural and Extraordinary abilities are not subject to dispelling or spell resistance.